# Instagram private API in React native using Expo cli

Tags: react-native, expo

Can anyone link any documents on using Instagram private API or Instagram web API with react native Expo Cli. I read about it and didn't find a way to do it due to the need for native code. However, I am unable to use XCode for several reasons.

Does anyone have a way to integrate or is anyone able to find any documents about using mentioned APIs (or modules however you want to call them) with Expo (problem lies mainly on the nodejs-mobile-react-native module as far as I have understood). Or is anyone able to link another framework with the capabilities of building Android and iOS applications with the same code or am I asking for impossibilities? I have tried flutter with flutter_insta but it has the limitation of getting only public account data etc.

Any help will be appreciated!